# itertools and strided list assignment

Tags: python, slice, python-itertools

Given a list, e.g. `x = [True]*20`, I want to assign `False` to every other element.

```
x[::2] = False
```

raises `TypeError: must assign iterable to extended slice`

So I naively assumed you could do something like this:

```
x[::2] = itertools.repeat(False)
```

or

```
x[::2] = itertools.cycle([False])
```

However, as far as I can tell, this results in an infinite loop.   Why is there an infinite loop?  Is there an alternative approach that does not involve knowing the number of elements in the slice before assignment?

EDIT: I understand that `x[::2] = [False] * len(x)/2` works in this case, or you can come up with an expression for the multiplier on the right side in the more general case.  I'm trying to understand what causes itertools to cycle indefinitely and why list assignment behaves differently from numpy array assignment.  I think there must be something fundamental about python I'm misunderstanding.  I was also thinking originally there might be performance reasons to prefer itertools to list comprehension or creating another n-element list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Tolonen pointed out in a concise comment, the reason why your itertools attempts are cycling indefinitely is because, for the list assignment, python is checking the length of the right hand side.

Now to really dig in...

When you say:

```
x[::2] = itertools.repeat(False)
```

The left hand side (`x[::2]`) is a list, and you are assigning a value to a list where the value is the `itertools.repeat(False)` iterable, which will iterate forever since it wasn't given a length (as per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)).

If you dig into the list assignment code in the cPython implementation, you'll find the unfortunately/painfully named function [`list_ass_slice`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/listobject.c#l614), which is at the root of a lot of list assignment stuff.  In that code you'll see [this segment](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/listobject.c#l646):

```
v_as_SF = PySequence_Fast(v, "can only assign an iterable");
if(v_as_SF == NULL)
    goto Error;
n = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(v_as_SF);
```

Here it is trying to get the length (`n`) of the iterable you are assigning to the list.  However, before even getting there it is getting stuck on [`PySequence_Fast`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/abstract.c#l2257), where it ends up trying to convert your iterable to a list (with [`PySequence_List`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/abstract.c#l2235)), within which it ultimately creates an empty list and tries to simply extend it with your iterable.

To extend the list with the iterable, it uses [`listextend()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Objects/listobject.c#l799), and in there you'll see the root of the problem:

```
/* Run iterator to exhaustion. */
for (;;) {
```

and there you go.

Or least I think so... :)  It was an interesting question so I thought I'd have some fun and dig through the source to see what was up, and ended up there.

As to the different behaviour with numpy arrays, it will simply be a difference in how the `numpy.array` assignments are handled.

Note that using `itertools.repeat` doesn't work in numpy, but it doesn't hang up (I didn't check the implementation to figure out why):

```
>>> import numpy, itertools
>>> x = numpy.ones(10,dtype='bool')
>>> x[::2] = itertools.repeat(False)
>>> x
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> #but the scalar assignment does work as advertised...
>>> x = numpy.ones(10,dtype='bool')
>>> x[::2] = False
>>> x
array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are attempting to do in this code is not what you think (i suspect)
for instance:
`x[::2]` will return a slice containing every `odd` element of x, since x is of size 20,
the slice will be of size 10, but you are trying to assign a non-iterable of size 1 to it.

to successfully use the code you have you will need to do:

```
x = [True]*20
x[::2] = [False]*10
```

wich will assign an iterable of size 10 to a slice of size 10.

Why work in the dark with the number of elements? use

```
len(x[::2])
```

which would be equal to 10, and then use

```
x[::2] = [False]*len(x[::2])
```

you could also do something like:

```
x = [True if (index & 0x1 == 0) else False for index, element in enumerate(x)]
```

---

EDIT: Due to OP edit

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) on cycle says it `Repeats indefinitely.` which means it will continuously 'cycle' through the iterator it has been given.

Repeat has a similar implementation, however [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) states that it
`Runs indefinitely unless the times argument is specified.`
which has not been done in the questions code. Thus both will lead to infinite loops.

About the `itertools` being faster comment. Yes itertools are generally faster than other implementations because they are optimised to be as fast as the creators could make them.

However if you do not want to recreate a list you can use `generator expressions` such as the following:

```
x = (True if (index & 0x1 == 0) else False for index, element in enumerate(x))
```

which do not store all of their elements in memory but produce them as they are needed, however, generator functions can be used up.

for instance:

```
x = [True]*20
print(x)
y = (True if (index & 0x1 == 0) else False for index, element in enumerate(x))
print ([a for a in y])
print ([a for a in y])
```

will print `x` then the elements in the generator `y`, then a null list, because the generator has been used up.

Comment: That is precisely what I want to do.  I'm coming from the perspective of a numpy user.  If you have `x=numpy.ones(10,dtype='bool')`, `x[::2]=False` sets the 0,2,4,6,8'th elements of the array to False.  I'd like to know why the equivalent fails for lists, even with itertools.

Comment: numPy treats things differently to normal python, with good reason usually, but in this case, `x[::2]` is returning a list of size `x/2` with `0,2,4,6,8...`th elements in it. To do it the normal python way, use the list comprehension for flexability.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
l = len(x)
x[::2] = itertools.repeat(False, l/2 if l % 2 == 0 else (l/2)+1)
```

Your original solution ends up in an infinite loop because that's what `repeat` is supposed to do, from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

> Make an iterator that returns object over and over again. Runs indefinitely unless the times argument is specified.

Comment: Why is the x[::2] asking for assignment infinitely?  There are only (in my original example) 10 elements that need assignment.  Why doesn't that set a limit on the itertools calls?

Comment: No, `repeat` produces an infinite number of elements _before_ it tries to assign it (therefore, we must limit the number of elements produced). For the assignment to x[::2] to work, you must pass the exact number of elements that you want to assign to the slice,

Comment: What about `cycle`?  I've used it before, and in other uses I've seen it generate new elements only when called.

Comment: The documentation also states that `cycle` "repeats indefinitely"

Comment: The point is: neither `repeat` nor `cycle` "know" when to stop producing elements, _you_ know that the list at the left-hand side of the assignment has a finite number of elements, but there is no way for the iterator called on the right-hand side of the assignment, to know that fact. It just keeps producing elements, since _you_ did not tell it to stop in any way.

Comment: That's a decent explanation.  But I'm still trying to figure out what's going on 'under the hood'.  `x[::2]` is equivalent to `x.__getitem__(slice(None,None,2))`, so the left side of the equation is a list.  From a little experimentation, I gather that the right side of the equation is turned into a list if it is not one, then assignment proceeds - so if the right side is an iterable, it needs to have the same number of elements as the left.

Comment: @keflavich, In x[::2] = y, y must be the same length as the slice, so Python has to iterate y to see how many items are in it.  Since cycle/repeat produce indefinitely, you get an infinite loop.  When you use cycle/repeat in something like zip([1,2,3],repeat(1)), zip stops calling repeat once it reaches the end of the first sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The slice `x[::2]` is exactly `len(x)/2` elements long, so you could achieve what you want with:

```
x[::2] = [False]*(len(x)/2)
```

The `itertools.repeat` and `itertools.cycle` methods are designed to yield values infinitely. However you can specify a limit on `repeat()`. Like this:

```
x[::2] = itertools.repeat(False, len(x)/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The right hand side of an extended slice assignment needs to be an iterable of the right size (ten, in this case).

Here is it with a regular list on the righthand side:

```
>>> x = [True] * 20
>>> x[::2] = [False] * 10
>>> x
[False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

And here it is with *itertools.repeat* on the righthand side.

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> x = [True] * 20
>>> x[::2] = repeat(False, 10)
>>> x
[False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```